# Passing asynchronous data from a web page to my window form C# .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, integration

I would like to make a web page able to communicate (asynch) with a softphone implementation based on a C# .NET windows form application. Ideally, the button nearby any phone number should send the string including the phone number and a few additional data to the softphone running locally. 
Windows form should receive the number and use it to make a call. 
The end of the call should be communicated back to the web page which initially started the call.
Being a beginner of .NET programming, which implementation could be the easiest and lightest to achieve these requirements? I am focusing on ASP .NET but is it really helpful and how? Many thanks

Comment: I think you have big confusion and misunderstanding on how software architecture should work. You can't control a Windows Client application (any technology) from a web page but the other way around. The ASP.NET or ASP.NET Web Api would be your slave, and the Phone or Client application would be your master. 
How do you think the web page is aware of the phone?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry I only explained at high level how the mechanism should work. I surely do not pretend to control the phone client application from the web page. Just looking for a way to make it possible as Skype already does in some web pages. After the click the phone number is retrieved by the softphone app which makes the call.  The phone has to be aware of what happens on the web page.

Comment: See my answer. Try SignalR

Comment: I saw an implementation which made sufficient to call an href from the page in the format href="sip:<phone_number>" to forward the number to the softphone client application. I was wondering on how this could be implemented

Comment: Your App needs to register a protocol handler on the browser, which depends from browser to browser. i.e. Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers. IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx#url_inv

Comment: Many thanks Tseng I already started to check your suggestions out and I let you know how It goes!

Answer (score 0):

Serverside technology and clientside technology are quite unrelated as the browser will be in the middle.
One possibility is to return a file with a custom extension from the website as you click on the phone number. The file extension can be linked in the local operating system (through a installer) with the client application so it will be opened automatically with you soft phone application.

This file can hold any data structure containing all the information you want to transport. (look for "xml serialization")

EDIT:
this solution makes you independent of sip protocol handler in the operating system ([set sip handler application in registry](http://www.oak-wood.co.uk/faq/content/5/13/en/how-do-i-register-a-url-handler-for-the-sip-protocol-in-windows.html)) and allows to forward more information about the person to be called than just the number.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). It's a library for real-time web communication.

You can host the SignalR app in an own process (self-hosting) or host it within your IIS Webserver.

Both your website and your .NET WinForm app connects to it. You can use [SignalR groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) to associate Website user to WinForms client.

Then you can send messages from your Website to the SignalR and broadcast it to a certain group (where your WinForm App is belonging to).

The ASP.NET website has plenty of tutorials on it.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started

This should also work with WinPhone Apps as long as SignalR/your ASP.NET website isn't locally hosted.

**Edit:**
Just some extra information:
SingalR requires Windows Server 2012 or higher to enable WebSocket support, otherwise it will have to fallback to alternative mechanism (Server Sent Events for HTML 5 or "Forever Frame"/Ajax Long Polling